# How to make a PDF form with javascript to concatenate two fields on click OK?

Tags: javascript, forms, pdf, acrobat

[image: Please watch this image before answering]

i want two concatenate the Username + Email Domain , On click OK button 
and Display result in Below Full Email field.

Javascript Code to do that please help

Comment: Please include your image in your question, rather than using an external link. As SO isn't a free coding service, please include what you've already done, and the problems/errors you've met. Then we can help you.

Answer (score 0):

In the Full Email field, add the following JavaScript to the mouse up action. You may need to edit the field names to match yours.

```
this.getField("Full Email").value = this.getField("username").value+this.getField("Email Domain").value
```